# SQLite - Python - referir a coluna de tabela num loop

Tags: python, sqlite

Estou fazendo um script no Python acessando base de dados SQLite.
Fiz um loop For mas não sei como pegar o valor de uma coluna na tabela.

Veja o exemplo:

```
cursor2 = cnx.cursor()
cursor2.execute("select * from despesas")
cursor2.moveToFirst()
cont = 0
lista = []
for (despesa) in cursor2:
    if permanente="S":
    elif:
```

Preciso verificar se o valor da coluna "permanente" da tabela "despesas" é "S" ou "N". A coluna "permanente" é varchar(1). Depois vou mudar para boolean. 
Como faço?

Answer (score 0):

Quando você escreve `select * from despesas` você está selecionando todas as colunas da tabela despesas.
Para selecionar apenas uma coluna específica, troque o `*` pelo nome da coluna desejada.

Então seu loop `for` pode ficar assim:

```
//Selecionando apenas a coluna "permanente" da tabela "despesas"
query = cursor2.execute("SELECT permanente FROM despesas")

for row in query:
    if row == 'S':
        código
    else:
        código
```

Comment: Obrigado. Ja ajudou muito. Agora eu quero usar o valor de outras colunas para criar um registro em outra tabela. Por isso usei *. veja a seguir:             if despesa[permanente]="S":
            elif:
                lista.append(despesa)
                ydespesa = [Despesa]
                yvencimento = [Vencimento]
                yvalor = [Valor]
                cursor3=cnx.cursor()
                cursor3.execute("INSERT INTO pagamentos VALUES(null,ydespesa,yvencimento,yvalor,null,null,null)")
                cnx.commit()

Comment: Por favor, edite sua pergunta e adicione esse segundo questionamento.